# Sending multiple emails php, but just arriving to first recipient

Tags: php, email, notifications, sendmail

Basically I need to notify certain users of something happening in the application.
I bring the users from the database, everything works fine, but when i send the emails, only the first one in the list receives it, I tried switching the order they are brought, and still, so is not about a particular mail client.

I tried sending one by one and now sending all together and neither seems to work.

Have this ever ocurred before? I'm using some amazon server, with linux, but is a client's client's server so i can't really stick my head all over the config.

```
$ul = $this->q2ar("SELECT * FROM usr WHERE role_id in(1,7)");
//get admins from db
$ntf = '';
foreach($ul as $usr){
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0 '." \r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . " \r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Centinelas <centinelas@serviciochevrolet.com.ec>' . "  \r\n";
    $body = "mail content";
    $ntf .= "'".$usr['email']."'".', ';
}
$ntf = substr_replace($ntf ,"",-2);
$ml = mail($ntf,'Nuevo Caso en Centinelas Chevrolet',$body,$headers,'- fcentinelas@serviciochevrolet.com.ec');
return('email where sent to :<br/>'.$ntf);
```

Comment: Did you echo the value of `$ntf` and check?

Comment: yep, it gives me the list of all the emails, also when i get the email on my account (when is the first one on the list, i see the rest of the emails in the to field)

Comment: Try sending one email at a time, moving the mail() function into the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending an email to one person, like yourself or the sender then using the Cc to send to the rest.

```
$ul = $this->q2ar("SELECT * FROM usr WHERE role_id in(1,7)");
foreach($ul as $usr){
    $ntf[] = $usr['email'];
}

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0 '." \r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . " \r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Centinelas <centinelas@serviciochevrolet.com.ec>' . "  \r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: '.join($nft,",") . "  \r\n";
$body = "mail content";

$ml = mail('centinelas@serviciochevrolet.com.ec','Nuevo Caso en Centinelas Chevrolet',$body,$headers,'- fcentinelas@serviciochevrolet.com.ec');
return('email where sent to :<br/>'.join($nft,","));
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole use the Cc: string.

```
foreach($ul as $usr){
    $ntf .= (($ntf=="")?"":", ")."'".$usr['email']."'";
}

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Centinelas <centinelas@serviciochevrolet.com.ec>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Centinelas <centinelas@serviciochevrolet.com.ec>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: '.$ntf.'' . "\r\n";
```

you have to add $ntf "CC:" to the HEADERS (for clarity it is often ok to send the mail to the sender)